# Bug with social networks and some character encodings

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, social-networking, encoding

Hi meta!

I've  just tried to "Share This" feature from http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16870/le-bon-usage-du-francais-french-usage then selected Twitter.

It ends up at this address : http://twitter.com/?status=Stack%20Exchange%20QnA%20site%20proposal%3A%20Le%20bon%20usage%20du%20fran%EF%BF%BDais%20[French%20usage]%20http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2Fi9nlSu with the message : `Stack Exchange QnA site proposal: Le bon usage du fran�ais [French usage] http://bit.ly/i9nlSu`

So there is a little problem with UTF-8 I guess, since the character should be `ç` which is not in ASCII set.

With mail I've got : `Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Le bon usage du franXais [French usage]` with a square instead of `X`.

It's ok for facebook.

It fails on [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Farea51.stackexchange.com%2Fproposals%2F16870%2Fle-bon-usage-du-francais-french-usage%3Freferrer%3DSwqiERtTE0tcIDk1Shz0UA2&title=Stack+Exchange+Q%26A+site+proposal%3A+Le+bon+usage+du+fran%EF%BF%BDais+[French+usage]&ro=false&summary=&source=) with `We’re sorry. Something unexpected happened and your request could not be completed. Please close this window and try again.`

I did not tried the rest of social networks.

#### EDIT:

The problem seems to originate from the area51 page at first. The links uses `fran%E7ais` instead of `fran%C3%A7ais`.

What is the function used to do this? Seems that the source charset is wrong here.

Comment: Oddly, the `http://twitter.com/?status=` URLs do not work for me at all. Shouldn't that include `home`, like http://twitter.com/home?status=My+Message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 2):

The `ç` is actually [Unicode U+00E7](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e7/index.htm), or UTF-8 `C3 A7`. Instead, in the URL one gets `EF BF BD`, which is UTF-8 for [Unicode U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm):

> used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode

So, displaying � is actually correct. And I guess one would see the very same sequence for any other non-ASCII character? Some erroneous double encoding that rightfully fails, maybe?

Using `C3 A7` works fine though, for Twitter:

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=Fran%c3%a7ais
https://twitter.com/?status=Fran%c3%a7ais
```